# How to randomly spawn prefabs on the X axis?

Tags: unity, c#, random, prefabs

I created an infinite runner game.

I need to make random spawning obstacles in 3D.

How do I randomly spawn prefabs on the X axis using a C# script?

Answer (score 1):

Modified from the [unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html):

```
//creates a position between -10 to 10 on the x-axis
float randomRange = Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f);
Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3(randomRange, 0, 0);

var alexsObstacle = Instantiate(
AlexsObstaclePrefab,
randomPosition,
Quaternion.identity);
```